# Convert SVG to AI in Bulk?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

Is there a tool to convert SVG to AI in bulk? Everytime I search for this I simply get online convertors that convert SVG to bitmap formats, or similar stuff. I would need an offline tool, and one that can do hundreds of files at a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some batch scripts for bulk-conversion of files using Illustrator:

- https://gist.github.com/seltzered/4405256
- http://rockfire.co/how-to-batch-convert-ai-to-svg/
- https://superuser.com/questions/100111/how-do-i-create-an-export-batch-script-in-illustrator-cs4-

Comment: Isnt this the wrong way around.

Comment: Yes many of them are the wrong way around but a script can easily be modified to get what you need. Usually just open it up and change which "filetype to open" (change *.src to *.dest) and change which "filetype to save as" in the same way.

Comment: You should accept this post then so it does not spook around the system.

Answer (score 4):

This batch conversion can be accomplished without scripting using Adobe Illustrator CC's actions palette —

Use the actions palette to create a new action and record the steps taken to convert a single file (i.e. Open an SVG and save as an AI file whilst recording the action).

Once the action has been recorded access the Action palette's 'batch' function (available within the Actions palette's hamburger menu).

1. Point at a source folder containing SVGs. (Select: Override Action "Open" commands)
2. Point to a destination folder for your Ai files (Select: Override Action "Close" commands)

Comment: it's now called Overide Action "Save" commands, instead of "Close" now, for anyone wondering

Answer (score 0):

Because SVG files open in Illustrator by default (at least on my Mac), I would just use Finder's Rename function to batch replace .svg with .ai. I tested and it appears as if it's AI file and still opens in AI. Not sure if this solves your issue but works for me. Good luck!